# NET.addAssembly returning strange Could to load assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, matlab

I have a strange issue while loading some assembly of mine in Matlab:

```
function [] = foo()
%[
    fold = 'c:\FolderWithAllAssembliesAndDependencies';

    try 
        NET.addAssembly(fullfile(fold, 'MainAssembly.dll')); 
    catch ex
        if (isa(ex, NET.NetException) && isfield(ex.ExceptionObject, 'LoaderExceptions'))
            error(char(ex.ExceptionObject.LoaderExceptions.Get(0).Message));
        else
            rethrow ex;
        end 
    end
%]
```

returns

```
Could not find 'SubAssembly, Version=3.0.58.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e33b67d3bb5581e4' or or one of its dependencies. File not found.
```

But if try to load this sub assembly by its own it is ok:

```
NET.addAssembly(fullfile(fold, 'SubAssembly.dll')); % No issue !!!
```

I tried a simple console program in C# (targetting .NET Framework 4.0) and I have no issue loading the main assembly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\FolderWithAllAssembliesAndDependencies\MainAssembly.dll"); // Works fine !!!
}
```

I'm using matlab R2015b and R2019a and targeted frameworks by the assemblies are the following:

- MainAssembly.dll => .NET Standard V2.0
- SubAssembly.dll => .NET Framework v4.6

I also tried modifying `matlab.exe.config` file (in matlab installation folder) to the following :

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.6"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

and restarting matlab, but it still fails to load the MainAssembly and I can't see what's wrong (i.e. no issue loading MainAssembly in simple console program above [even if it is targeting only .NET framework v4.0]).

Answer (score 1):

```
    MainAssembly.dll => .NET Standard V2.0
    SubAssembly.dll => .NET Framework v4.6
```

That won't work (probably). Your app assembly is starting with a .NET 2.0 context that allows for newer .NET runtimes and then tries to load an assembly that was compiled with .NET 4.6.

You could try and load the `SubAssembly` first, which should spin up a .NET 4.6 context and then load the `MainAssembly`. An easier solution would be to just compile your `MainAssembly` with .NET 4.6. Source to backup claim: [social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bef443cc-5413-4322-8d9a-117abd2386d3/loading-an-assembly-which-was-build-with-net-40-from-an-net-20-assembly-migration-szenario?forum=netfxgeneralprerelease) by a Microsoft employee.

Or could could create a .dll that is compiled with .NET 4.6 that references your `MainAssembly.dll` and then load this newly created assembly in Matlab.

If you really want to dig into this, or believe this to be a different problem, you could utilize [fuslogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer). That tool will list all binding requests and what assembly requested what dependency and wether or not it succeeded.

Comment: Thank I'll try into that before and let you know